# What is the break-even point for instancing?

Tags: opengl

I have read that instancing in OpenGL makes drawing thousands of objects faster. But, if you use instancing and only draw one object, is it much slower? If so, what order of magnitude of objects do you need for instancing to be an improvement? Just a few? Tens? Hundreds?

Some context (in case I have an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)); if I have to write code for instancing anyway, it would be  easier to just leave it on all the time.

Comment: I doubt using instanced rendering with one instance is much different performance-wise from using the regular draw commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to these types of questions tend to be somewhat repetitive: Try different options, and benchmark them on the platform(s) you care about. There's really no way to give a definitive answer that will necessarily apply to every possible platform.

That being said, I would not expect instanced rendering to add significant overhead on hardware that fully supports it. Instanced rendering is not a very recent feature. Based on the history I could find, it was part of DX10 (released in 2006) and OpenGL 3.1 (released in 2009). So it seems very likely that any moderately recent hardware (DX10 level and later) can support it efficiently.

On recent hardware, non-instanced rendering could be just a special case of instanced rendering where only a single instance is drawn. There might be a little more state setup, but overall it could be basically no additional overhead.

In general, it's not uncommon that features are supported on hardware that does not really have full support for the feature. In those cases, the driver will sometimes have to jump through hoops to provide the feature, often with lower efficiency and additional CPU overhead. It's not impossible that this could be the case for instanced rendering on some platform, which brings us back to the start: Benchmark!